# Can I solve this problem with Dynamic Programming?

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, greatest-common-divisor, lcm

How I find among all pairs `a` and `b` with a "least common multiple" LCM(a,b) = 498960 and a "greatest common divisor" GDM(a, b) = 12 a pair with minimum sum `a + b`?

I solved this with O(n^2) time:

```java
public class FindLcmAndGcdClass {
    private int findGcd(int a, int b) {
        if (a % b == 0) {
            return b;
        }
        return findGcd(b, a % b);
    }

    private int findLcm(int a, int b, int gcd) {
        return (a * b) / gcd;
    }

    private void run() {
        int minSum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int foundNumberOne = 0;
        int foundNumberTwo = 0;
        for (int i = 12; i <= 498960; i += 12) {
            for (int j = i; j <= 498960; j += 12) {
                int gcd;
                if (i < j) {
                    gcd = findGcd(j, i);
                } else {
                    gcd = findGcd(i, j);
                }
                int lcm = findLcm(i, j, gcd);

                if (gcd == 12 && lcm == 498960 && i + j < minSum) {
                    minSum = i + j;
                    foundNumberOne = i;
                    foundNumberTwo = j;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(minSum);
        System.out.println(foundNumberOne);
        System.out.println(foundNumberTwo);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var o = new FindLcmAndGcdClass();
        o.run();
    }
}
```

And it executes quite slowly! I guess the problem can be solved with Dynamic Programming. Can anyone help with more fast solution?

Comment: *"How I find a minimum sum value of a and b"* Could you please explain what you mean by "a minimum sum value of a and b"?

Comment: @Stef I mean among all pairs a, b with LCM(a,b) = 498960 and GDM(a, b) = 12 I need find a pair with minimum sum a + b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this question can be solved with dynamic programming, but I think of a solution with time complexity `O(sqrt(LCM * GCD))`.

It is well known that for any two integers a and b, `LCM(a, b) * GCD(a, b) = a * b`. Therefore, you can first calculate the product of the gcd and lcm, (which is 5987520 in this question). Then for all its factors under `sqrt(LCM * GCD)`, let `a` be one of the factors, then `b = LCM * GCD / a`. Test if gcd(a, b) = the required gcd, if so calculate the sum `a + b`, then find the minimum among the sums, and you are done.

Comment: Could you please explain `Then for all its factors under sqrt(LCM * GCD)`. What factors? And why `sqrt` when `a` and `b` can be different numbers? Maybe just divide numbers from 12 to 498960?

Comment: I meant all factors of LCM * GCD. I used sqrt because for every correct pair (a, b), (b, a) is also a correct pair. Therefore, you can just loop to sqrt, then for a correct pair (a, b), you can count it twice.